# Hibernate criteria queries - Query Conditions

Tags: spring, hibernate, jquery-plugins, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I am using spring 3.0 and I am using the JqGrid plugin. I am working on the search feature which sends a json string with all the search criteria. Here is what the string can look like.

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"firstName","op":"bw","data":"John"},{"field":"lastName","op":"cn","data":"Doe"},{"field":"gender","op":"eq","data":"Male"}]}
```

If you look at the **"op"** property inside the **rules** array, you will see the operation which must be executed. The Jq-grid has the following operations

['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en','cn','nc']

which corresponds with

['equal','not equal', 'less', 'less or equal','greater','greater or equal', 'begins with','does not begin with','is in','is not in','ends with','does not end with','contains','does not contain']

I plan to use hibernate criteria searching to enable the search feature. For this I am using Jackson's **ObjectMapper** to convert the incoming JSON into Java. This is all well and good. Here is my code that converts the json.

```
public class JsonJqgridSearchModel {

    public String groupOp;

    public ArrayList<JqgridSearchCriteria> rules;
}


public class JqgridSearchCriteria {

    public String field;

    public String op;

    public String data;

public SimpleExpression getRestriction(){
    if(op.equals("cn")){
        return Restrictions.like(field, data);
    }else if(op.equals("eq")){
        return Restrictions.eq(field, data);
    }else if(op.equals("ne")){
        return Restrictions.ne(field, data);
    }else if(op.equals("lt")){
        return Restrictions.lt(field, data);
    }else if(op.equals("le")){
        return Restrictions.le(field, data);
    }else if(op.equals("gt")){
        return Restrictions.gt(field, data);
    }else if(op.equals("ge")){
        return Restrictions.ge(field, data);
    }else{
        return null;
    }       
}

}

@RequestMapping(value = "studentjsondata", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String studentjsondata(@RequestParam("_search") Boolean search ,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
        if(search){
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                    JsonJqgridSearchModel searchModel= mapper.readValue(httpServletRequest.getParameter("filters"), JsonJqgridSearchModel.class);
                    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    session.beginTransaction();
                    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);                   
                Iterator<JqgridSearchCriteria> iterator = searchModel.rules.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){  
                    System.out.println("before");
                    criteria.add(iterator.next().getRestriction());
                    System.out.println("after");
                }                   
                } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }else{//do other stuff here}
```

This is where the problem comes in. How do I transalate the jqGrid operation into the equivelent hibernate command ? For example
 **"cn"** should correspond with

`criteria.add(Restrictions.like("firstName", myJsonJqgridSearchModel.data));`

Comment: I made some edits and the above reflects my current code, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I've just written almost identical code to what you have above (mine doesn't use JqGrid however).  I'm wondering if your problem is specifically related to the "cn" - LIKE condition?  I had problems with this - I had to specify the MatchMode to get the "contains" like I wanted:

```
return Restrictions.ilike(
    searchCriterion.getPropertyName(),
    searchCriterion.getValue().toString(),
    MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
```

I found that without specifying the MatchMode, it was generating SQL as:

```
WHERE property LIKE 'value'
```

By specifying the MatchMode.ANYWHERE, it generated SQL as:

```
WHERE property LIKE '%value%'
```

which is the "contains" operation that I was expecting.  Perhaps this is your issue as well?

Comment: Thank you very much for the heads-up, i will try that out and see how it goes.