# Spring MVC - no DAO service layer, how to get current session for criteria query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria

I have no DAO service layer in a spring MVC project. IN my controller, I wish to create a criteria query. For this I need a session object to call the "createCriteria(myClass.class)".

How do I get the session object ?

I saw some people were using the HibernateUtil class like "HibernateUtil.currentSession()". I tried this but the import cannot be resolved. I posted some of the relvant code to address another issue here [Hibernate criteria queries - Query Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234133/hibernate-criteria-queries-query-conditions)

Can someone please offer some form of guidance in this regard, Thanks.

Comment: spring has an excellent integration with hibernate. creating a **Query** in your controller is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was solved by using the entity manager exposed in the parent entity class. I have a class called person and in there is placed a transient method as follows

```
@Transient
public static Collection<?> searchResults(JsonJqgridSearchModel jsonJqgridSearchModel){
    HibernateEntityManager hem = Person.entityManager().unwrap(HibernateEntityManager.class);
    Session session = hem.getSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
    Iterator<JqgridSearchCriteria> iterator = jsonJqgridSearchModel.rules.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){  
            criteria.add(iterator.next().getRestriction());
        }
    return criteria.list();     
}
```

The main thing is how the HibernateEntityManager and the Session was obtained. Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

HibernateUtil is a class you are supposed to create according to your own needs. Here's [the corresponding docs section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-helpers).

Comment: It is recomended that this approach not be used for production, however it offered some insight

Comment: @Binaryrespawn yup, in newer versions of the Hibernate docs, they don't even mention it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the dispatcher-servlet.xml. Sessions (Hibernate), tx managers are set up in the context for later access. old 2.5 example .. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html

Answer (score 0):

`HibernateUtil` is a class from the Hibernate tutorial. It's *not for real use*. Don't use it for anything but the tutorial. If you're already using Spring, it has [excellent Hibernate integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate). Just do it the right way from the start.